# C# - Recompiling old code, running into errors (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

First and foremost, I've never worked with C#, or any compiled language for that matter. So I'm hoping I'm just doing something wrong here.

We have an old in house app, written in c# that has some smtp settings hard coded that need to be changed. I have the source files, and even the .sln visual studio project file. So I open the project in vs, make the required changes, and go to build- however I'm running into errors (Build -> Build 'Autodocs' (the name of our app)):

```
Build started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: AutoDocs, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\shared\New folder\AutoDocs\Microsoft\Office\Interop\Word\Documents.cs(10,38,10,54): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'CustomMarshalers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.InteropServices' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
1>C:\shared\New folder\AutoDocs\AutoDocs\modules\DWStorer.cs(7,7,7,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DocuWare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

So does anybody have any suggestions for a c# newbie like me? Anything I should have to do when copying a project dir from the server to my pc to build it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know what kind of program it is? Windows? ASP.NET? MVC?

The errors are shown, but let's go through them:

```
1>C:\shared\New folder\AutoDocs\Microsoft\Office\Interop\Word\Documents.cs(10,38,10,54): 
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'CustomMarshalers' does not exist in the
namespace 'System.Runtime.InteropServices' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

First, look in this document:

`C:\shared\New folder\AutoDocs\Microsoft\Office\Interop\Word\Documents.cs`

Somewhere in that file, when viewing in Visual Studio, you will see the word `CustomMarshalers`, and it needs to be referenced.

So, in your project, you will need to right-click the References section and add that missing reference (if it isn't there already):

[image: screenshot]

Also, at the top of your `Documents.cs` file, you need to have a line like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

See Microsoft's documentation here: [System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.custommarshalers)

Here is your second error:

```
>C:\shared\New folder\AutoDocs\AutoDocs\modules\DWStorer.cs(7,7,7,15):
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DocuWare' could not be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Similar to the first error, this one is having an error in the `DWStorer.cs` file because it cannot resolve the keyword `DocuWare`.

DocuWare is a third party tool that must be added to your references and added to the top of your `DWStorer.cs` file.

[DocuWare](https://start.docuware.com/)

You may have to go to the link above to download their tool if you do not have it in your project somewhere.

Comment: Hey man, thanks so much for all of the effort you put into your answer. First of all, not sure what type of program. I know it's made up of c# files and requires .net. But, that might apply to each of the types you listed. I only ever work with Python, php, js, etc. (interpreted or right-on-time type languages), so I'm sorry if I sound ignorant or uninformed when it comes to the build process. 
Anyways, yep, this program runs to automate workflows between our CMS and docuware, so docuware is all setup and in place. Hopefully just need to fix the missing references.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I'm a Windows C# developer trying to learn Angular, jQuery and MVC. I ask questions and people answer like I'm an idiot because I've been on here so long they think I know all of it. **Right-Click** on your project and go down to Properties. It should list a page with information about what you are working on.

Comment: Well, it looks like I don't have the docuware package/sdk installed... which is environment specific and I'll get it sorted out. But the thanks  again for the tip on references thats just what I needed.